# what is the definition for Array.data in Angular.Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, validation

I have a code like below :

```
var territories = {};
if(territories.data) {
  deferred.resolve(angular.copy(territories));
} else {
  endpoints.getAllTerritories().then(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    territories = resp;
    deferred.resolve(territories);
  });
}
```

Can anyone give defintion of how Array.data is used, like here in the code we see `territories.data`. It simple seems like checks if the array has data or not, but I need to know  the exact definition and if possible any documentation link for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, territories is not array, it is JSON, which is Javascript Object Notation. Try exploring JSON instead of Array.data.

Comment: but how could one understand it is json not regular array? please help

Comment: In JS,var territories = {}; will make object which is commonly known as JSON
and var territories = []; will create simple array.

Comment: @user59759 did you get it?